# iOS - Swift draw shape inside current view controller

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, shapes

I'm not really sure where to start and was looking if someone could point me in the right direct.

I am building on top of the following project: https://github.com/hoiberg/HM10-BluetoothSerial-iOS

My goal is to be able to draw a big rectangle in the middle of the screen on top of the box which displays the serial messages (SerialViewController.swift)[I will later remove these messages as they are remaining for debugging purposes] and be able to color the top half of the rectangle and the bottom half of the rectangle independently (these will be set when a message reaches a certain condition, which I have already implemented).

I want to be able to manipulate both the top half and bottom half of the rectangle with the following function:

```
func uiColorFromHex(rgbValue: Int) -> UIColor {

// &  binary AND operator to zero out other color values
// >>  bitwise right shift operator
// Divide by 0xFF because UIColor takes CGFloats between 0.0 and 1.0

let red =   CGFloat((rgbValue & 0xFF0000) >> 16) / 0xFF
let green = CGFloat((rgbValue & 0x00FF00) >> 8) / 0xFF
let blue =  CGFloat(rgbValue & 0x0000FF) / 0xFF
let alpha = CGFloat(1.0)

return UIColor(red: red, green: green, blue: blue, alpha: alpha)
```

}

So then I can manipulate the color of the regions respectively. Ie:

```
let myColorValue = 10

self.topHalfRectangle.hexStringToUIColor(myColorValue)
```

Any help to point me in the right direction would be appreciate as I can't seem to make anything work!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this in your ViewController...

```
// Set a couple of constants to hold the shapes

let topHalfRectangle = CAShapeLayer()
let bottomHalfRectangle = CAShapeLayer()

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    // Create shape layer paths for the top and bottom rectangles
    // Note that these will fill the entire view,
    // inset as necessary.
    topHalfRectangle.path = UIBezierPath(rect: CGRect(x: 0.0, y: 0.0, width: view.frame.size.width, height: view.frame.midY)).cgPath
    bottomHalfRectangle.path = UIBezierPath(rect: CGRect(x: 0.0, y: view.frame.midY, width: view.frame.size.width, height: view.frame.midY)).cgPath

    // Add the shape layers to the view
    view.layer.addSublayer(topHalfRectangle)
    view.layer.addSublayer(bottomHalfRectangle)
}
```

To set the color:

```
topHalfRectangle.fillColor = uiColorFromHex(myColorValue).cgColor
```

Incidentally, setting a UIColor from a hex value is a common task so I'd recommend extending UIColor to provide this feature.

```
import UIKit

extension UIColor {

    /// Create color from RGB hex
    ///
    /// - Parameter fromHexValue: Hexadecimal integer value

    convenience init(fromHexValue: Int) {

        // &  binary AND operator to zero out other color values
        // >>  bitwise right shift operator
        // Divide by 0xFF because UIColor takes CGFloats between 0.0 and 1.0

        let red =   CGFloat((fromHexValue & 0xFF0000) >> 16) / 0xFF
        let green = CGFloat((fromHexValue & 0x00FF00) >> 8) / 0xFF
        let blue =  CGFloat(fromHexValue & 0x0000FF) / 0xFF
        let alpha = CGFloat(1.0)

        self.init(red: red, green: green, blue: blue, alpha: alpha)
    }
}
```

Then just use it by `let color = UIColor(fromHexValue: 10)`.

Comment: Thank you for that!